# Printing output from json

Tags: python, json

I am still new to python, and brand new to json. I am trying to go through output that is in json. I am not yet sure which fields will need to be printed out, but I do know that two of them will be needed.

How could I change:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('out.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

pprint(data)
```

to print out say, field one, and field two?

I figure if I can print field one, and two, I can play around with it until I find the right fields. I imagine this is a derp level question, but being able to print specific fields is what I need to be able to do.

Comment: `print(data['field1'])`...!?

Comment: If you know the name of the field you will like to print --> print data['field_name'] (python 2...) or print(data['field_name']) (python 3) 

Once you've loaded the data_file which will become a dictionary and from that you can print any keys you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json.load` is returning python obj (https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) so depending on content of 'out.json' it can be either dict, list or few other types.

In case of dictionary you can go with `data['key']` or if it's list go with `data[index]` - where index is `1,2,...`

For looping use `for` ie for list:

```
for elem in data:
    print(elem)
```

of for dictionary:

```
for key, value in data.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am getting closer. 

The out.json looks like:
{"success":true,"response":[{"category":"Utility","score":120.0}]}

If I say:
print(data['category'])

I get an error.

Comment: Look at your data. 'category' is not a root element but part of 'response' list. So in this cace you should do `print(data['response'][0]['category'])' because 'category' is a part of first element in a list contained in a 'response' key of main dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You could have find it easily in  [python's json documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Here data is a `dict` type object. You can get any value by using the corresponding key like this:

```
print data['field']
```

But it will throw a `KeyError` if the `field` key is not present in the `dict`. For avoiding this issue you can use the `get()` method.

```
print data.get('field')
```

This will return `None` in case of missing key.